# Using sed to find text BEFORE a string

Tags: bash, unix, sed, scripting, output

So I'm trying to extract URLs from url files
and i need some kind of descriptor for the file--

If I have something like

```
param5x57389dwordhereparam3904
```

and I want to extract `wordhere`, I know I can use

```
$(sed -n 's/param5x57389//p' $f)
```

to get `wordhereparam3904`

so how do I go about taking off that last part?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please ask *one* question per problem. I've edited the question. You can find the other part in the edit history. Please make another question out of it because both problems aren't related.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following sed command:

```
sed '/param5x57389d/ s/param5x57389d\(.*\)param.*/\1/' "$f"
```

Comment: It gives *wordhereparam* not *wordhere*